# Form.is_valid() returns true when it shouldn't?

Tags: django, validation, django-forms, django-views, authentication

This is my view:

```
def registerView(request):
    form = RegistrationForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
            password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
            email=form.cleaned_data['email']
        )

        username=form.cleaned_data['username']
        password=form.cleaned_data['password1']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('/home/') 

    variables = {'registerForm':form}
    return render(request, 'register.html', variables)
```

and this is my RegistrationForm:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):

    username = forms.CharField(label='Username', max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email')
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput()) 
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput()) 

def clean_password2(self):
    if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data:
        password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']
        if password1 == password2:
        return password2
    raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords do not match.')

def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data['username']
    if not re.search(r'^\w+$', username):
        raise forms.ValidationError('Username can only contain alphanumeric characters and the underscore.')
    try:
        User.objects.get(username=username) 
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return username 
    raise forms.ValidationError('Username is already taken.')
```

and this is my template:

```
<form method="post" action="/regsiter/">{% csrf_token %}
    <h6>username:</h6>
    {{ registerForm.username }}

    <h6>email</h6>
    {{ registerForm.email }}

    <h6>password:</h6>
    {{ registerForm.password1 }}

    <h6>confirm password:</h6>
    {{ registerForm.password2 }}

    <input type="hidden" name="next" />
    <input type="submit" value="register" />
</form>
```

Now for some reason, when I go to my template and not fill anything in (leave all fields blank) and try to register, it redirects to /home/ which means it is marking the form as valid (if form.is_valid(): returns true for some reason) even when all the fields are blank. I even tried using a username which exists but it still said that the form is valid. Any idea why?

Comment: for your form action, did you spell it wrong here or is it also wrong on your template?

Comment: @SunnySydeUp spelled it wrong in the template as well.. that is what turned out to be the problem -.-. Thanks! You can put that as the answer and I'll mark it, just encase someone in the future gets errors because of a spelling mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form action was spelt incorrectly and so it was never hitting the `registerView`. It should be:

```
<form method="post" action="/register/">
```